# Which of the two words (At & By) should be used in the expression below

Tags: word-usage

In my lesson plan, on the objectives I wrote:

> By the end of the lesson, the students should be able to...

So when my first supervisor came he said that the word 'by' should be replaced with 'at'. When another came he said otherwise. Now I am confused which of them is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly fine in this situation.

**By** a time means at that time *or before*. If your boss says she wants your report "by 3 o'clock," she expects you to give it to her at 3 o'clock or sometime earlier.

**At** a time means *at* that time, not before. If your boss says she wants your report "at 3 o'clock," the strict interpretation is that she expects it at 3 o'clock but not before.

In your situation the difference between the two prepositions is irrelevant. I would probably use "**by** the end of the lesson," but "at" sounds fine to me too.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I'm not sure I'd call the difference "irrelevant." To me, _**at** the end of the lesson_ implies the student won't be able to accomplish the learning objective until the lesson is complete, whereas _**by** the end of the lesson_ implies the student might be able to accomplish the objective midway through the lesson. So I'd call the difference "subtle" rather than "irrelevant." Also, as a matter of convention, one might want to use "at the end of the lesson," but "by the end of the course," since (presumably) each lesson is tied to one or more course objectives.